# I added a comment, but it didn't trigger any response. Should I instead open a new problem report?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I posted a problem report for GRPC which contained full simplified source code, and then *later* posted a proposed "workaround" which pointed to a possible bug in GRPC, but have received no comments on the "workaround".

Should I instead have opened a new problem report entirely?

For reference, the problem is found at this URL:
[UPDATED: found a "fix" in the generated code! (was: RPC failure code 14 in our simple GRPC example program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313159/updated-found-a-fix-in-the-generated-code-was-rpc-failure-code-14-in-our-s)

Comment: Just to make sure: when you write 'problem report', you mean 'question', right? This isn't a place to post actual bug reports, you should send those to the project's support team or bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Updating your original question was the right thing to do. However, you might want to try a more "natural" title, avoiding words like 'update'. Edit it as if it was a new question and you already knew all the information you added in the update.

I can't comment on the actual quality of the question, but it looks OK at first sight. Perhaps you are able to reduce the code required to reproduce this problem? That might get people more interested.

It's also possible that there are few or no people around who are able to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I originally thought it was a problem in *my* code, and have lately become more suspicious that it's a problem in the GRPC code, which suggests maybe I should delete this and re-open it under github/grpc, but I can wait a bit to see if anyone can give me guidance here.